# Adjust the time of the GPS

Tags: geotag

I'm taking some photos of my city and at the same time I'm recording the track so that I can geotag the images when done.

The problem was that couldn't do it with all the software offered (HoudahGeo, Geotag...). I started wondering why this couldn't work and I finally discovered that when I opened my gpx, the track points were one hour less than the creation date of the images. I don't know why? The timing should be the same because Im using the same device.

If you have any idea about how to deal with this i would be pleased.

Comment: are you in a timezone with daylight saving? or one hour ahead of UTC?

Comment: I'm with GMT + 1 daylight saving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GPS is recording the time in UTC (or GMT) so you need to adjust the times of your photos to be in UTC. Most geotagging software should take care of this for you automatically, but may there is a setting for timezone in your programs.